# How to remove similar HTML tag close to parent using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Here is my HTML code:

```
<div class="img-area text-center frustrated">
<img class="delete" style="height: 12px; float:right; padding-right:5px; cursor: pointer;" src="/linkmo/images/closeicon.png" offset="2">
<a class="loc" href="#">
<img id="imagelocation2" class="imagelocation" style="height:110px; width:105px;" alt="" src="/linkmo/upload/224927120.jpg" offset="2">
</a>
</div>
```

When the user clicks on image having class `delete` then I change the src attribute in img tag with the ID `imagelocation2` using ajax.

What I want is that when image src is changed the img tag having the class `delete` should be removed.

What I have tried in my ajax success function:

```
 $('#imagelocation' + id).attr('src', '/linkmo/images/placeholder.png');//Changes the src of img tag, works fine
 $('.delete img[offest='+id+'').remove();//Does not work
 $('#imagelocation' + id).parent().closest(".delete").remove();//Does not work
```

What I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

USe like this `find` instead of `closest`

```
$('#imagelocation' + id).parent().find(".delete").remove();
```

Because `closest` search for the parent elements. While `find` search for child elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.siblings()` to target the image with class `.delete`:

```
$('#imagelocation' + id).siblings('.delete').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a type in your javascript.

```
$('.delete img[offest='+id+'').remove();
```

should be

```
$('.delete img[offset='+id+']').remove();
```

offest -> offset

Comment: No typo in the code, typo here when I wrote here, thats not the issue. spellings are correct in source code.

Comment: Try $('img.delete[offset='+id+']').remove() '.delete img' is trying to remove an image that's a descendant of .delete